# How do I handle database ORM situations like this in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

```
params['blog_posts'] = Content.objects.get(user = blah)
params['other_vars'] = "other stuff"
params['votes'] = 4245

if request.GET.get("format") == "json":
    response = json.dumps(params)
    return HttpResponse(response)
else: 
    return render_to_response("posts.html", params, RequestContext(request))
```

In my template, I do stuff like this:

```
{% for p in blog_posts %}
    The author is: {{ p.user.get_profile.about_me }}
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, I really utilize the Django's foreign key/database models.  The problem is...how do I shoot all of these foreign models to JSON?

Even if I serialize `blog_posts` using `django.core.serializers`, the JSON won't contain the `.user` model, and of course won't contain the `.get_profile` model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to have your model class itself contain the knowledge of how to serialize itself:

```
class MyBaseModel(BaseModel):
    def serialize():
        abstract # this will throw an error if it's called without being overwritten

class Post(MyBaseModel):
    title = db.stringProperty()
    body = db.textProperty()
    user = db.referenceProperty(User)

    # etc etc etc
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'title' : self.title,
            'body' : self.body,
            'user' : self.user.serialize()
            # etc
        }
```

Comment: What is "MyBaseModel"? I don't do any of that. I just do : class Content(models.Model):

Comment: Ah, I usually insert my own base model between the framework's base and my true models, so I can make changes across all classes if I like.  For instance, upon save() I like to set updated_at and created_at to the current time.